# sequelize - Specifying attributes for SELECT queries while using inner join

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs

I want to fetch from the main table account and compare it with account history.
there is a relationship On To many between the two table

```
SELECT account."userName", (account."postNumber" - accountHistory."postNumber") AS postNumber
    FROM public."Accounts" AS account  INNER JOIN public."AccountHistories" AS accountHistory
    ON account."userName" = accountHistory."userName" 
    WHERE accountHistory."scrappingDate" = '2022-01-08 23:59:39+01'
    ORDER BY postNumber DESC;
```

My question is how can I make the query with sequilize?
I tried but I could not change the name of the attribute and do the subtraction

```
await this.accountRepository.findAll({    
    where: {'$accountHistory.createdAt$' : '2022-01-08 23:59:39+01'},
    include: [{
      model: AccountHistory,
      required: false
    }],
    attributes: ['userName',['$accountHistory.postNumber $', 'postNumber '],postNumber ],
   order: [[$accountHistory.createdAt$', 'DESC']],
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use [Sequelize.literal](https://sequelize.org/v6/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal) to perform the calculation as an aliased attribute, e.g.:

```js
const { literal } = require('sequelize')

await this.accountRepository.findAll({    
    where: {'$accountHistory.createdAt$' : '2022-01-08 23:59:39+01'},
    include: [{
      model: AccountHistory,
      required: false
    }],
    attributes: [
      'userName',
      [
        literal('"account"."postNumber" - "accountHistory"."postNumber"'),
        'postNumber'
      ]
    ],
   order: [[$accountHistory.createdAt$', 'DESC']],
})
```

That exact syntax might not work depending on your SQL dialect - I'm not familiar with the `$` symbols you are using